# Why doesn't BigQuery update if I cleanup Google Storage at the end of my MapReduce Job?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, mapreduce, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I have a Mapper Pipeline I modeled after the log2bq example on Google's App Engine.

The breakdown:

1. I upload a file to be processed into Blobstore
2. I use a Mapper pipeline to iterate over the file, do some work with it, and use an output writer to write the results to Google Storage in CSV format
3. I then submit a BigQuery Job to consume the newly created file to populate into a table
4. I query the table and write the ouput of the query into Blobstore
5. User downloads the end result

This is all done by using a number of pipelines. My problem is if I enable the deletion of the file created in step 2 to happen after step 4, then my BigQuery table doesn't update. I tried two methods:

1. I created a cleanup pipeline to run at the end of the two main pipelines that only deletes the files created
2. I tried to delete the files at the end of step 4 (within the same pipeline)

You can see both methods commented out in my code below. Why does BigQuery not update if I try and delete the file? Am I deleting it too soon? It would sound like the case, but I'm pretty sure the code that runs the delete function runs only after the output file has been written into Blobstore. Any help would be much appreciated!

My main pipeline is `Blobstore2BigQueryMaster` below

```
class Blobstore2GoogleStorage(base_handler.PipelineBase):
    def run(self, blobkey, bucket_name):
        yield mapreduce_pipeline.MapperPipeline(
            "<NAME>",
            "<MAPPER>",
            "mapreduce.input_readers.BlobstoreLineInputReader",
            "mapreduce.output_writers.FileOutputWriter",
            params={
                "input_reader" : {
                    "blob_keys": blobkey,
                },
                "output_writer": {
                    "filesystem": "gs",
                    "gs_bucket_name": bucket_name,
                    "mime_type": "text/csv",
                }
            },
            shards=24)

class GoogleStorage2BigQuery(base_handler.PipelineBase):
    def run(self, file_names, filekey):
        bq = bigquery.BigQueryApi()
        gspaths = [f.replace('/gs/', 'gs://') for f in file_names]

        result = bq.submit_job(jobData(<TABLE_NAME>, gspaths))
        yield BigQueryImportCheck(result['jobReference']['jobId'], filekey, file_names)


class BigQueryImportCheck(base_handler.PipelineBase):
    def run(self, job, filekey, file_names):
        bq = bigquery.BigQueryApi()
        status = bq.get_job(job_id=job)

        if status['status']['state'] == 'PENDING' or status['status']['state'] == 'RUNNING':
            delay = yield pipeline.common.Delay(seconds=1)
            with pipeline.After(delay):
                yield BigQueryImportCheck(job, filekey, file_names)

        yield BigQueryExport(filekey, file_names)  


class QueryCompletionCheck(base_handler.PipelineBase):
    def run(self, job):  
        bq = bigquery.BigQueryApi()
        status = bq.get_job(job_id=job)
        if status['status']['state'] == 'PENDING' or status['status']['state'] == 'RUNNING':
            delay = yield pipeline.common.Delay(seconds=1)
            with pipeline.After(delay):
                yield QueryCompletionCheck(job)

        yield pipeline.common.Return(status)


class BigQueryExport(base_handler.PipelineBase):
    def run(self, filekey, file_names):        
        bq = bigquery.BigQueryApi()
        #Submit Job to BigQuery Here
        #<REMOVED>

        response = yield QueryCompletionCheck(insertResponse['jobReference']['jobId'])

        #WRITE QUERY RESPONSE TO BLOBSTORE HERE
        #<REMOVED>

        #files.delete(",".join(file_names))
        yield pipeline.common.Return(response)

class Blobstore2BigQueryMaster(base_handler.PipelineBase):
    def run(self, filekey, blobkey, bucket_name):
        file_names = yield Blobstore2GoogleStorage(blobkey, bucket_name)
        synchronize = yield GoogleStorage2BigQuery(file_names, filekey)
        yield CleanupCloudStorage(synchronize, file_names)


class CleanupCloudStorage(base_handler.PipelineBase):
    def run(self, synchronize, file_names):
        #files.delete(",".join(file_names))
        yield pipeline.common.Return('Done')

def jobData(tableId, sourceUris):
    #Configuration for the BigQuery Job here including
    #'createDisposition':'CREATE_IF_NEEDED'
    #'writeDisposition':'WRITE_TRUNCATE'
```

Answer (score 1):

It's safe to delete the CSV file from Google Cloud Storage as soon as the BigQuery load job finishes.

I would recommend checking the completed jobs for errors to see if that reveals the reason for the import failure, and if possible, confirm that your import completion check is not returning prematurely.